# How to Compress Image File In Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, image, express, upload, image-compression

i write a REST API with express and node js  and upload image with

> multer

and i want resize image before save . for example if a image size is 2MB i want convert less to 1Mb.
And I don't want to change the height and width of the photo as well as its extension
can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-image-resizer

```
npm i -D node-image-resizer


import resizer from 'node-image-resizer';

(async () => {
  await resizer('./image.jpg', setup);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sharp library https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp

Install library: `npm install sharp`

Resize image

```
const sharp = require('sharp');
let bufferImgCompressed = await sharp(yourImgBuffer)
.resize({ width: 100, height: 200 })
.toBuffer()
.then(data => { return data; })
.catch(err => { console.log('Error on compress'); });
```